# React - onClick() with an <a> tag with an href - disable link for just one div

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a setup that looks like this.

```
<a href="link">
   <button onClick={() => setShowDisc(false)}></button>
</a>
```

When I click on the button, the onClick triggers successfully, the problem is it also opens the link for the outer  tag.  I need to disable this for just the one button. I have tried setting the onClick to `onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); setShowDisc(true)}}` but that doesn't work to fix my issue for some reason.

Comment: Putting a button inside of a link is semantically... strange.  What's the goal of this structure?

Comment: Just change the href => href="#". This prevents to redirection.

Comment: You want to use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default link behavior

Comment: @David It is an ad where I want the entire container to be clickable to go to a link, but there is also a single button on the ad to expand some text.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you that worked perfectly!